# When to save a mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is an architectural question. I have models like this:

```
var foo = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  bars: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Bar'}]
});
var FooModel = mongoose.model('Foo', foo);

var bar = new mongoose.Schema({
  foobar: String
});
var BarModel = mongoose.model('Bar', bar);
```

Then I want to implement a convenience method like this:

```
BarModel.methods.addFoo = function(foo) {
  foo.bars = foo.bars || []; // Side note, is this something I should check here?
  foo.bars.push(this.id);

  // Here's the line I'm wondering about... Should I include the line below?
  foo.save();
}
```

The biggest con I see about this is that if I did include `foo.save()` then I should pass in a callback to `addFoo` so I avoid issues with the async operation. I'm thinking this is not preferable. But I also think it would be nice to include because `addFoo` hasn't really "addedFoo" until it's been saved... Am I breaking any design best practices doing it either way?

Comment: Please comment when you downvote. I don't see how this question is against the question asking guidelines. This is a legitimate question.

Comment: I'm not sure. What are you trying to do? You are trying to create model level function which is get argument of another models document and save that itself. And you want to avoid callback. am I unserstanding correct?

Comment: Voting is one of the great mysteries of StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If adding the "foo" and saving were a common usage pattern (and that it were the last operation dealing with the `BarModel` so that multiple `saves` aren't done unnecessarily), I'd expect it to be named appropriately so that it's obvious it has a clear side effect, like `addFooAndSave`. But to be consistent with Node.JS conventions, I'd also add the callback as you mentioned (and you can just pass it through to `save`):

```
BarModel.methods.addFooAndSave = function(foo, callback) {
  // foo.bars = foo.bars || []; // not needed, auto initialized to empty
  foo.bars.push(this.id);

  // Here's the line I'm wondering about... Should I include the line below?
  foo.save(callback);
}
```

This way you can just call:

```
bar.addFooAndSave(function(err, bar, numAffected) { 
    // response
});
```

Otherwise, if saving isn't as common, I'd make it an explicit step and add the "foo" as a method as you have, and then explicitly call `save` on the model instance.

Answer (score 1):

> foo.bars = foo.bars || []; // Side note, is this something I should check here?

No, mongoose will handle that for you. `foo.bars` will always initially be an empty array.

I think that implicit save in other helper methods is a poor design choice. Your API audience knows they are making DB records and they understand the concept of `save()`, which is straightforward. Be consistent with the rest of mongoose in having operations on a model instance be in-memory until an explicit `save()` is called.

But absolutely if you do end up doing any I/O in a method you write, you must adhere to the node convention of accepting a callback function and calling it with `error, results` on completion. Otherwise you are setting your application up for brittleness and race conditions and all manner of nastiness.